# Keep relative size with non-orthogonal transformation

Tags: opengl, transformation, projection, orthogonal

I'm writing a shader that display text label using textured quads (nothing complicated).

A label has an origin (vec3) and a direction (vec3) and I choose a fixed
orthogonal direction in the shader (see below). Each glyph is described by four
vertices and each vertice position is referenced using an offset (vec2) giving
advances along tangent and orthogonal direction

```
 uniform vec3 origin;
 uniform vec3 direction;
 uniform float scale;
 attribute vec2 position;

 vec3 tangent = normalize(direction.xyz);
 vec3 ortho   = cross(tangent, vec3(0,0,-1));
 vec4 P = vec4(origin + scale*(position.x * tangent + position.y * ortho),1.0);
```

This works without problem.

Now, I would like to introduce a user defined transformation function
(e.g. polar projection, but it is not known in the shader). The problem is that
I would like to keep my label size constant independently of the transform and
relative to a reference point. For example, this does not work:

```
vec4 P = transform(origin + scale*(position.x * tangent + position.y * ortho));
```

Because the four points defining the glyph may have "different" transforms if
the transform is not orthogonal (like the polar projection). Using a reference point R, I can have a fixed orientation and size using:

```
vec4 T = transform(R + scale*tangent*position.x) - transform(R);
vec4 O = transform(R + scale*ortho*position.y) - transform(R);
vec4 P = transform(origin) + T + O;
```

But I would like to keep the new orientation while keeping the size constant
relative to the reference point. Any idea ?

[image: Screenshot of current transformation]

Finally the solution was:

```
vec4 T = transform((origin+scale*tangent)) - transform(origin);
T = scale*normalize(T);
vec4 O = transform((origin+scale*ortho)) - transform(origin);
O = scale*normalize(O);
vec4 P = transform(origin) + position.x*T + position.y*O;
```

but zooming information (present in the transform) is lost.

Comment: My concern is not for different glyphs but for the four vertices composing a glyph. The whole label is already encoded into a vertex buffer using a texture atlas (see https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl). But if the transform is not orthogonal, then the four glyph points  have different relative scales and this results in weird scaling.

Maybe a bit of context could help: I'm doing scientific visualisation and I offer the user the possibility to define its own transform as required for example in cartography. I would like to add labels to axis ticks (see http://glumpy.github.io).

Comment: From the looks of things, the point `P` that you are computing in the very first shader is in clip-space (NDC space in fact, because the `w` component is **1.0**). That would be an excellent coordinate space to _stay_ in when computing the other two vectors. In this coordinate space, the viewing volume maps to [**-1.0**,**1.0**] and you can easily assign constant sizes relative to your viewport dimensions. 1 unit in the Z direction is always 1/2 of your depth range, 1 unit in the X direction is always 1/2 your viewport width and 1 unit in the Y direction is always 1/2 your viewport height.

Comment: Or, more generally, `w`-units in any direction in clip-space is half of the visible coordinate range. It seems your `transform (...)` function introduces a `w` component, whereas the original `P` was a constant **1.0**. You can accomplish uniform scaling if you use a constant `w` (your reference point's `w`) across all 4 points.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Your comments about the `w` component makes sense but it hard to debug in my case because the transform also includes a trackball transformation and x,y,z scale transforms.

Since I know the origin (start) of the label, my idea was to compute the transform of the origin, origin+tangent and origin+ortho such as to get transformed tangent (`transform(origin+T)-transform(origin)`) and ortho (`transform(origin+O)-transform(origin)`) but them I'm stuck with the `w`component.

Comment: Finally the solution I envisaged seems to work. I only needed to add the scale factor when computing transformed tangent and ortho. Thanks for your helpful comments.